# Why do the following code prints the stack trace and why is a.toString() in the return statement not giving an error or exception?

Tags: java, string, reflection, annotations

Following is the complete code -

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class A2<T> {
    T ob;
    A2(T ob) {
        this.ob = ob;
    }
    @Annos(str="T example")
    T retob() {
        return ob;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Annotation a = null;
        try {
            Class<?> c = this.getClass();
            Method m = c.getMethod("retob");
            a = m.getAnnotation(Annos.class);
        }catch(NoSuchMethodException NSMe) {
            NSMe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return a==null?"EMPTY":a.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new A2<Integer>(2).toString());
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Annos {
    String str();
}
```

If I have override the `toString()` method then how can `a.toString()` in the return statement as well as in the main method work?

Here is the output -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: A2.retob()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2227)
        at A2.toString(A2.java:20)
        at A2.main(A2.java:28)
EMPTY
```

Why is it not able to get the method `retob`?

Comment: `a.toString()` is calling toString on the `Annotation` object returned by `m.getAnnotation(Annos.class);`. The `toString` in your `main` method is calling `A2::toString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to change

```
Method m = c.getMethod("retob");
```

to

```
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("retob");
```

This is needed because your `retob` method is not public.

From [the documentation of getMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...)):

> [The class's] declared public instance and static methods as returned by getDeclaredMethods() and filtered to include only public methods that match given name and parameterTypes

This means that `getMethod` uses `getDeclaredMethod` but then ignores the method if it's not `public`. Using `getDeclaredMethod` directly solves that problem.

About your question regarding the toString:

`return a==null?"EMPTY":a.toString();` still works because `a` is `null`. That's why `"EMPTY"` is returned.